# Casting generic pointers in c

Tags: c, pointers, casting, void-pointers

I found this code in a book, trying to explain how generic pointers works using this to copy one matrix to another one.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define FILAS 2
#define COLS 3

void copiarMatrices(void *, void *, int);

int main(){

    int m1[FILAS][COLS] = {24, 30, 15, 45, 34, 7};
    int m2[FILAS][COLS];

    copiarMatrices(m2, m1, sizeof(m1));

    for (int i = 0; i < FILAS; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) printf("%d ", m2[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void copiarMatrices(void *dest, void *orig, int n){
    char *destino = (char *)dest;
    char *origen = (char *)orig;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        destino[i] = origen[i];
    }
}
```

The book said that the only data type that we could cast the void pointers was char because other data types are not allowed because of the bytes size.

I don't understand this and also if I execute the program with either int or double data type on void pointers the program get stuck for a few seconds and then finish well.

Comment: A void pointer can't assume any "shape" of what it points to. The `size` parameter is passed in as `sizeof`. You may want to read the three first sentences of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the book is saying is that the result of the "sizeof" operator is the expression argument's size in bytes. If instead you were to specify "sizeof(m1) / sizeof(int)" then instead of "char *" you would need to cast the parameters to "int *" because you would then be passing the number of ints to copy instead of the number of bytes.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I think I've got it. However, do you know where I can find more information about how variables are stored in memory?

Answer (score 0):

Function `copiarMatrices` copies buffer of any size. Let's imagine that buffer `orig` is 5 bytes. If you cast to `int *` inside `copiarMatrices` and `int` is 4 bytes and I want to copy all 5 bytes from `orig` to `dest` than `n` will not be integer (if n=1 than 4 bytes will be copied, if n=2 than 8 bytes will be copied but I need to copy 5 bytes). So, we can agree that copying will be by bytes and `n` means number of bytes which will be copied. In general you have to call `copiarMatrices(m2, m1, FILAS * COLS * sizeof(int));`

Answer (score 0):

You do not need any special functions. You function `copiarMatrices` can be reduced to `memcpy(m2, m1, sizeof(m1));`

Some remarks.

1. Do not use `int` for sizes. Use the correct `size_t` type instead.
2. Try to be `const` correct.
3. Return a reference to the destination object, It will allow the function to be used in the expressions.

Your function prototype should be: `void *copiarMatrices(void *, const void *, const size_t);`. If you want to make the compiler life easier you may: `void *copiarMatrices(void restrict *, const void * restrict, const size_t);`